# Excel: How to open Data Entry Form up to New Record, not first record

Tags: excel, forms

I was able to find a solution on here on how to use vba to open a data entry form and it works perfectly. Thank you!

However it always opens to the first record (either thru vba or the standard excel Form button), and I have to hit the 'new' button once the data entry form is open to get to a blank 'new record'.

Is it possible to get the data entry form to automatically open to the blank 'new record' every time it opens? Thus eliminating an extra (and what seems like, unnecessary) step in my data entry process?

This would also eliminate the chances of the first record being accidentally altered because someone wasn't paying attention and started editing before hitting 'new'.

Any help would be appreciated, because I can't find any answers to this after countless google searches.

Comment: What solution did you find? You should link it for others to know what you are working with

Comment: Could you please provide the code you are working with and point out any errors you may be running into please?

Comment: `Sub Create_New_Entry()
    'Opens the Data Entry Form
Range("B2").CurrentRegion.Name = "database"
ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm

End Sub`

As mentioned, it opens and works fine, but it opens to the first record in my table. Just curious how/if I can get it to open to a new blank record instead